# How to give only a part of an object a ring texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

I managed to give a ring texture to an object, but I only want to restrict that texture to a part of an object, as highlighted in the picture.

How can I do that? I tried to mix in some color ramps as factors, min/max settings in the coordinate mappings but couldn't get it to work.

[image]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh/

Comment: Since it seems you're designing a material for one specific object, why not just assign the faces of that one part to a different material that uses that texture?

Comment: Cheers, glad you got it worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a second material to the material slots of the object and then select all the vertices/faces you want to assign this material too in edit mode and hit the "assign" button in the materials property tab:

[image]